# Android & custom views & custom xml attributes

Tags: android, xml, view, custom-controls

Say i have a valid custom view, named **com.package.MyCustomView** (MyCustomView extends LinearLayout or any View)

I can use this in a activity layout like this

```
<com.package.MyCustomView
        android:id="@+id/myView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

But i would like to have something like this:

```
<com.package.MyCustomView
        android:id="@+id/myView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        MyCustomView_attribute1="100"
        MyCustomView_attribute2="fantastic"/>
```

I'm imagining that in case of valid android xml attributes like **android:layout_width** the associated `value (match_parent, wrap_content)` will be set on a specific attribute of the parent View object (by use reflection or whatever.. ). I also am aware of the existence of the namespace (that line: `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`)..

In any case I would like something of the same kind - custom xml attributes for my custom for my view...

Is this possible? If yes - how? please give some details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a stylable resource and some custom attributed with it. [Official android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can perform like this...it will work

```
  <com.example.application.Drawer
         xmlns:my="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.application"
         android:id="@+id/drawer"
         android:layout_width="301dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         my:content="@+id/content"
         my:handle="@+id/handle" >
```

But one thing is that you should have the above package in src